# Protect from bots creating multiple free accounts and uploading files

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, security, registration, dropbox

I am developing a web for my university where users can create an account and upload images.  Images are private and can only be seen by the person who uploaded them. For instance, is like a cloud file system.

Each user have a free account with 500MB. I am using Amazon S3 to store the images, that is to say storage implies costs.

**How can I avoid that bots upload millions of MB? How can I avoid that a bot creates million of new accounts and upload 500MB per account without affecting the user experience?**

On one hand I definitely don't want to put a CAPTCHA in the registration form because it negatively affects the conversion rate. On the other, I don't want to pay thousands of dollars because a bot upload million of dummy images.

Does anyone know whether Dropbox, Google Drive, etc, suffers from this (content uploaded by bots)? It seems that is not a problem because I couldn't find anything about it. All spam related problems I could read about only covered spam in forums. It makes sense also. Spam in forums can be read by other users. Spam in a service like Dropbox or Google Drive reaches no one. Nonetheless I have to protect it to avoid cost surprises.

Comment: But there are already so many such services...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, without using CAPTCHAs this can be done:

- Set up monitoring systems that warn for specific abuse patterns (the same IP uploading lots of data and creating new accounts repeatedly).
- Throttle users that follow those patterns; this will hopefully make them realize and make the process worthless. If this fails, then disable those accounts and have their owners mail/talk to you in order to explain what's happening.
- Since you say it's a system for your university, make users provide proof of enrollment (e.g. an university e-mail address) in case of abuse.
- Have this forbidden usage explicit in your terms of use.

Of course, a smart enough bot can work around all those problems.

For a more advanced solution, you might try some machine learning or AI that learns about normal and abnormal usage patterns, then applies that information to judge a possible abuser.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the hints! However, what do you mean with an AI agent that learns about abnormal usage. Can you point me to some references? Do you know where they are libraries in Rails for that?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to :

1. make users register using their email
2. don't allow multiple accounts for a single email
3. send them an email registration confirm, and deactivate the "unconfirmed" accounts after a short amount of time (eg 3 days)

AFAIK, Drupal embeds this kind of controls out-of-the-box or with little effort (and no programming).

This won't solve all your problems, but in fact it will reduce the risk of bot exploits.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you need a registration, there are two points to tackle this problem - make sure no bots register and/or limit the number of uploads.

I personally would use both points. For the user signup, design a login form where the user has to enter its email address, send them a mail with a link in it and activate their account only after clicking this link. Or let the user solve a simple math question on signup.

For the second point, you can store the number of uploaded bytes per user and time. You can then set a quota on allowed upload usage per time, for example you may not upload more than 10MB per hour. If a user hits this limit more than n times, you can deactivate his account.

And: set up and alerting and monitoring system. For example monitor the number of non-activated users, monitor the amount of uploads etc. and set up alerts if these exceed a certain threshold.

The above mentioned methods may not be perfect and probably won't block out all bots, but they will at least make it way harder for bots to upload unwanted data. Also these methods are quite simple, so you can start of with your project and see if this is really a problem. And if you get bots to upload data, you will at least receive alerts and can invent a better solution afterwards.